# Weird function definition syntax in JS

Tags: javascript, methods, ecmascript-6

I've discovered this piece of code in the Meteor.js tutorial. It's ES2015:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'tasks.insert'(text) {
    check(text, String);

    // Make sure the user is logged in before inserting a task
    if (! this.userId) {
      throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized');
    }

    Tasks.insert({
      text,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      owner: this.userId,
      username: Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId).username,
    });
  },
});
```

And I'm curious about that way of defining functions. As we can see, `Meteor.methods` is given an object as a parameter, and that object contains functions as its props' values. But what a heck is that:

```
 'tasks.insert'(text) {
```

?? I expect 'tasks.insert' to be a string representing the prop name and that prop name should be mapped to a function that performs inserting. but why isn't it like

```
'tasks.insert': (text) => {
```

or

```
'tasks.insert': function(text) {
```

What a pattern is that and how does this can even be a valid JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a ES6 [syntatic sugar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions).

Example:

```
var a = {
  foo: 'bar',
  log() {
    console.log('hi');
  }
}

a.foo // 'bar'
a.log() // 'hi'
```

Just the same as if you've done `log: function { console.log('hi') }`

Comment: Thank you and sorry for such a stupid question. I just didn't know how to call it to search for it and decided that placing a code sample would be more  convenient

Comment: [If a function is the value of a property, it gets its name from that property.](http://www.2ality.com/2015/09/function-names-es6.html#methods-in-object-literals)